# Techniques to evenly display a bunch of nodes in a tikz document

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

To replicate the following picture (namely the evenly laid nodes a, b, c, d -- and I could want in the future to even have multiple rows, instead of just one) one can do one of multiple things: 
[image]

1. Manually hardcode the coordinates of each one of the nodes (this is what I did, for I don't know tikz / latex that well);
2. To create an invisible arrow from left to right and then make use of `pos=0`, `pos=0.33`, `pos=0.66` and `pos=1` to evenly display the nodes across the row;
3. Use a matrix? I think this would work as long as I could set the matrix width / height and as long as nodes would actually get evenly laid out. I don't know if this is doable?
4. Is there any other technique? Maybe by using trees?

This is a fairly known situation, so I'm looking for the best way of approaching this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a matrix allows you to do that. I added a style for the roof such that you can entirely focus on the contents of the matrix.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[roof/.style={path picture={
\draw[#1] ([xshift=\pgflinewidth/2]path picture bounding box.south west)
|- ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth/2,yshift=-\pgflinewidth/2]path picture bounding box.north east)
-- ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth/2]path picture bounding box.south east);
}}]
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,{nodes={text width=1cm,align=center}},
 roof=dashed,label={[anchor=south west]north west:Artifactory/Nexus}]
 { a & b & c & d \\
  & & & \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]